# How can i echo value from database INTO html <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I echo values that are submitted from a form on another page (which they are submitted into the database) into an HTML  tag as options?

This is my latest code and I'm still stuck here. When I clicked on the drop-down list, it still shows nothing.

```
<select name="comName" id="comName" class="form-control" required>
  <?php include('db_company.php');
  $query_option = "SELECT * FROM company";
  $result = mysqli_query($query_option);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<option value='{$row['comName']}'>{$row['comName']}</option>";
   }
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: okay, first things first, you need to turn on error reporting when you're on development phase

Comment: Hi Kevin! Thank you for your reply. I just added <?php error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); ?>. Is that alright?

Comment: the answers below forgot the fact that you need to pass the connection object in `mysqli_query`. and there's no `company` index in your `$row` array since you only selected `comName` column in your query. so it should be infact `$row['comName']` instead of `company`. `company` is the table name. `comName` is the column name. but if you have turned on error reporting right from the beginning, you would have gotten the information already

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your explanation. I guess I need to learn about error reporting first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes that you have done in here.First of all I would like to suggest you to start using [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)  using,

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If you have used error reporting from the beginning I believe you would have noticed all the issues that you are facing now.

1.You need to use the DB connection when you are using  [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
 $link = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DATABASE);
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$query_option);
```

2.You are using the wrong value inside the `while` loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo "<option>".$row{'company'}."</option>";
    }
```

You are getting `comName` from the query so you have to use `comName` instead of `company`.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<option value=".$row{'comName'.">".$row{'comName'}."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hirumina! It's working now. But I am still curious about the error reporting thing. Do I include the 3 lines of code on top of each PHP file?

Comment: no.they are just 3 different ways to do it. Just have a look at the link that I have added. You will be able to get an idea on it.

Answer (score -2):

Your echo in row is wrong

```
<?php include('db_company.php');

  $query_option = "SELECT * FROM company";
  $result = mysqli_query($query_option);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['company']}</option>";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Hi Jerson! Thank you for your reply. I have edited the code and my select tag still not showing anything. Do you think it has something to do with my PHP code?